# GPS Coordinates on Test Developer Phone

Tags: android, gps, coordinates

My code is taking coordinates of a position at one given time, and then displaying Lat/Long coordinates.  I think my code is right, but where the problem lies is giving GPS permission to the phone.  I am using a Samsung Nexus S, and I have all proper drivers installed, but there is no network on the phone.  I was told that GPS should still work and should be able to retrieve coordinates.  I have the, "Use GPS Satellites" setting enabled, and have given the permission in the  manifest, as seen here in the manifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

I threw in all possible location permissions just in case I was missing something, hopefully that isn't a problem.

As for my code I have this in the onCreate method (class? I'm not sure of its proper name)

```
    double[] gps = getGPS();
    TextView tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.gpsCoordinates);
    tv.setText("Latitude: " + gps[0] + "\nLongitude: " + gps[1]);
```

And then a private method in the GPS class to actually get the coordinates

```
    private double[] getGPS() {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  
        List<String> providers = lm.getProviders(true);

        /* Loop over the array backwards, and if you get an accurate location, then break out the loop*/
        Location l = null;

        for (int i=providers.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
                l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
                if (l != null) break;
        }

        double[] gps = new double[2];
        if (l != null) {
                gps[0] = l.getLatitude();
                gps[1] = l.getLongitude();
        }
        return gps;
```

I believe I pulled this code off of stackoverflow and a few other forums and then tweaked it a bit.

Comment: If you can install something like the Google Maps application on the phone it may fix whatever in the setup is wrong and get GPS working.

Comment: I have Google Maps installed, but it says, "network failure -- this application requires a working data connection"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

Add above permissions.May be this will help you.

Comment: Thanks! I actualoly plugged in my regular phone that had a network and such and it worked!  But i do see i am missing the access_fine_location.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

Ref:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Comment: Thanks! I actually plugged in my regular phone and it worked just fine, but thanks for pointing out that i was missing the access_fine_location!